# Redirect to 404 if unauthorized angular

Tags: angularjs

I am using the rootscope event in run function to check for entitlements like so

```
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
        $http.get('auth/urlentitlementcheck').then(function(response) {
            if (!response) {
                $state.go('app.unauth');
            }
        });
    });
```

But the problem is my controller functions are still getting called before this redirect happens.Is there another way to check for entitlement so that is happens before anything is called or loaded or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: wrong tag; angular1 question belong to angularjs

Comment: It is caused, because two independent things happen simultaneously: controller's initialization and request to 'auth'. You can create base controller, where you will check on auth and redirect to 404 page, if needed, and then stop further controller initialization.

Comment: you might need an interceptor (`$httpProvider.interceptors`)